# How to align HoloLens holograms relative to anchors in the Unity editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I am trying to align holograms relative to WorldAnchors without manually placing them in-app. Is there any way of visualizing WorldAnchors in the Unity editor to align objects relative to their positions? I see anchor data in the Device Portal, is this at all related to WorldAnchors?

Ideal workflow being:

1) Scan a room for the first time, obtaining a room mesh .obj through Device Portal. Simultaneously run an assistant Unity app and place anchor(s) for later reference (in room corners for example).

2) Import the .obj into Unity, along with Device Portal anchors if possible.

3) Transfer these WorldAnchors to a new Unity project and align holograms relative to the anchors.

4) Run this new app for the first time on HoloLens and have holograms properly positioned in space without additional adjustment of anchors by the user.

---

Here is an example using Vuforia, but I would like to use WorldAnchors (or the anchors in Device Portal somehow) for a markerless solution: https://youtu.be/W7z2sggDGoo?t=1689

The script referenced here 404s: https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/530

https://forums.hololens.com/discussion/10725/placing-holograms-at-predefined-locations-in-spatial-mapping-hololens almost provides a solution, but still fails to explain how anchors and the room mesh can be aligned in development for accurate placement upon opening the app.

Thank you!

Edit - Here is a similar question: [Placing objects at set locations in a pre-scanned room](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46950969/placing-objects-at-set-locations-in-a-pre-scanned-room) Is there a better solution than "placing all the objects manually in some config first-run of the app"?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know world anchors only exist during runtime and there is no way to export them to unity or already add predefined ones in unity.

I had a similar problem and went with vuforia ImageTargets and it works quite nice.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make use of the **WorldAnchorStore** (`UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Persistence`). This allows anchors to be persisted on the device across sessions and between apps, and (off the top of my head) is probably the source of the anchors you see in Device Portal.

If you're using the *Mixed Reality Toolkit* in your project then there's a helper, **WorldAnchorManager** (found in Common/Scripts) that wraps the underlying functionality.

Comment: We will be making use of the WorldAnchorStore to load the holograms as oriented in space after placing anchors in the first run of the app. Is there any way to work with those anchors as they relate to the space, ideally relative to the exported .obj mesh? For example, I place an anchor above the door on the first run, then place an object in the doorway in the Unity editor, and upon building the app a second time see that object in the doorway?


I see the HoloLens 2 can export anchors through the Device Portal, so this may not be available functionality for HoloLens 1.